# How to quickly print Tensorflow results to TXT?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to know how I can efficiently save the NN weighting factors to TXT file by Tensorflow. The flowing is an example that I try to save the results from Tensorflow to TXT by using `fp.write`.  However, it takes more than 1 days when I have 4 layers NN with 1000 hidden units in each layer.

```
fp = open('NN_for_Dymola.txt', 'w')

#############################
fp.write("********** W1 **********\n")

fp.write("[")
for i in range(n_hidden_1):
    fp.write("{"),
    if i == n_hidden_1-1: 
        for j in range(n_input):
            if j == n_input - 1:
                fp.write( '%1.10f' % sess.run(weights['h1'][j,i]) ),
            else:
                fp.write( '%1.10f,' % sess.run(weights['h1'][j,i]) ),
        fp.write( '}' ),
    else:
        for j in range(n_input):
            if j == n_input - 1:
                fp.write( '%1.10f' % sess.run(weights['h1'][j,i]) ),
            else:
                fp.write( '%1.10f,' % sess.run(weights['h1'][j,i]) ),
        fp.write( '},' ),        
fp.write( ']' )

fp.close()
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't write to file all the time. Put stuff into a string variable and only occasionally flush that to the file.

Comment: @friesel Would you please give me an example?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The overhead comes from calling `sess.run()` once per *element* of the weight matrix. You can call this once per matrix, and operate on a Numpy array instead.

---

I suspect the source of the slowness is this expression, which is evaluated for every element of the weight matrix:

```
sess.run(weights['h1'][j, i])
```

Why is this slow? First of all, TensorFlow will construct a new slicing operator to extract the element at index `[j, i]`, then invoke the runtime to run a step that extracts this value. TensorFlow is designed to be efficient when you define an operator once and use it many times.

Fortunately, you do not have to access the individual elements this way. You can call `sess.run(weights['h1'])` once to get a Numpy array containing all of the weights, and then write out its elements. For example, the following code should be much faster:

```
h1_val = sess.run(weights['h1'])

fp = open('NN_for_Dymola.txt', 'w')

#############################
fp.write("********** W1 **********\n")

fp.write("[")
for i in range(n_hidden_1):
    fp.write("{"),
    if i == n_hidden_1-1: 
        for j in range(n_input):
            if j == n_input - 1:
                fp.write( '%1.10f' % h1_val[j,i] ),
            else:
                fp.write( '%1.10f,' % h1_val[j,i] ),
        fp.write( '}' ),
    else:
        for j in range(n_input):
            if j == n_input - 1:
                fp.write( '%1.10f' % h1_val[j,i] ),
            else:
                fp.write( '%1.10f,' % h1_val[j,i] ),
        fp.write( '},' ),        
fp.write( ']' )

fp.close()
```

You may be able to achieve even faster results using [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), but that method gives you less control over the formatting.